# Write rspec for method inside method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
  def some_helper(exam)
    x = 1
    y = 2
    if condition1
       x = 3
       y = 4
    end
     if condition2
       x = 5
       y = 6
    end
    return_something_base_on_x_y(x,y)
  end

def return_something_base_on_x_y(x,y)
   return "#{1}/#{2}"   if x==1, y==2
   return "#{3}/#{4}"   if x==3, y==4
   return "#{5}/#{6}"   if x==5, y==6

end
```

i will call in view like this

```
some_helper(exam)  # exam is an object
```

How can i write rspec for  some_helper ? Can i write something like bellow. Only test the argument pass to method

```
describe "#some_helper" do
  let(:exam) { Exam.create exam_params }
  context "condition 1" do
     it do
       expect "some_helper" already call return_something_base_on_x_y with arguments(1,2) inside them
       expect "some_helper" already call return_something_base_on_x_y with arguments(3,4) inside them
       expect "some_helper" already call return_something_base_on_x_y with arguments(5,6) inside them
     end
  end
end
```

Can i avoid to write like

```
expect(some_helper(exam)).to eq "123"  # and 456.
```

Because if condition is more complexity, i have to get a list of return_something_base_on_x_y result.

Answer (score 0):

You can set expectations on a method before it is called by using a [double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/basics/test-doubles):

```
it "sets an expectation that a method should be called"
  obj = double('obj')
  expect(obj).to recive(:foo).with('bar')
  obj.foo('bar')
end
```

The example is failed if `obj.bar` is not called.

You can set expectations on an object after the call is done by using [spies](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies):

```
obj = spy('obj')
obj.foo('bar')
expect(obj).to have_recived(:foo).with('bar')
```

This allows you to arrange your tests after the *act, arrange, assert* pattern (or *given, then, when* in BDD terms).

> Can i avoid to write like
>
> `expect(some_helper(exam)).to eq "123"  # and 456.`

Yes, but it might actually degrade your tests. Stubbing can mask bugs and makes your code more about testing the implementation (how the code does its job) then the behavior (the result).

Stubbing is most suitible when the object you're testing touches an application boundry or is not idempotent (like for example a method that generates random values).

Comment: This answer doesn't have an example with the code in the question as its unclear where the`some_helper` and `return_something_base_on_x_y` methods are defined. Its not rocket science though and you should be able to adapt it to your use case.